# Websphere Application Server : Clustering

Tags: linux, websphere

So I cannot wrap my head around clustering in `Websphere`. The first issue I'm having is starting the deployment manager. To start it I need a profile. To create the profile I found this command within `IBM` documentation:

```
manageprofiles.sh -create -templatePath profileTemplates/dmgr/ -isDefault 
    -profileName dmgr
```

But profileTemplates/dmgr/ does not exist, does it exist in a different place, or have i missed something while installing `Websphere`?

Comment: Are you sure that you have installed Network Deployment edition version?

Comment: That... could be the problem! I have "WebSphere application server 8.5.5.1". Is clustering not available with this?

Comment: All depends how you obtain distributive? Usually you can download ND version from Partner World or Passport Advantage. If you download your version direct from web site, you will have  WebSphere Application Server Liberty.

Comment: I got the trial version of Websphere Application Server, which I understood was a fully featured 30 day trial.

Comment: Did you download WebSphere Application Server Network Deployment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you see only "default" and "management" directories under **WAS_HOME/profileTemplates** then most likely this is BASE edition. You can run versionInfo command from WAS_HOME/bin and for Network Deployment it should show some thing like

---

**Name                  IBM WebSphere Application Server Network Deployment**

**Version               8.5.5.1**

**ID                    ND**

---

The ID is showing ND. If your ID shows BASE /Express then there would be no option to create Deployment Manager profile. You would need to install ND code.

To download Trial version of WebSphere Application Server Network Deployment
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ws/wasnetwork/

To download Licensed version from Passport Advantage 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27038624

VS, opinions are my own and not those of my employer

Comment: Well, I feel foolish! Thanks for the help!